# Is taking advantage of someone else's lack of knowledge considered a fraud?

Tags: fraud

Say, Person A owns a rare postage stamp which is worth 2000€ according to the stamp collector community, but A doesn't know the worth.

Person B sees that A has a rare stamp and offers to buy it for a fraction of its worth. B offers A 100€ for the stamp and A agrees happily.

Later, A finds out the true value of the stamp and wants it back. A claims that B scammed them.

Is B guilty of fraud, simply for not telling A how much the stamp is worth?

Comment: You might want to add your location, as this might change the answers.  I want to add another wrinkle...  If the above is not fraud, would it become fraud if B specifically tells A that "the stamp is only worth 100 Euros"?

Comment: I'd consider it fraud, as that is a false statement

Comment: @James To answer your question: No, because that is still B's statement of opinion. It would be a fraudulent representation only if B told A something like "The stamp collector community values it at 100€" despite knowing that this is false.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

UK-based answer here:

The crux of your question revolves around whether the buyer(B) had committed an illegal act by **withholding information** that would have prevented the seller(A) from selling the good at the price he did. The act that B would seemingly be guilty of would be *fraudulent misrepresentation*

A misrepresentation is a *false statement* of fact or law which *induces the representee to enter a contract*.

The important thing here is if there is a "false statement".

In your scenario, there was **no false statement made**, let alone one which induced A into selling his stamp to B.

So there is no fraudulent misrepresentation, or misrepresentation of any kind.

Looking at the law of fraud:

s3 Fraud Act 2006: A person commits fraud by failing to disclose information when =>

The defendant:

1. failed to disclose information to another person
2. when he was under a legal duty to disclose that information
3. dishonestly intending, by that failure, to make a gain or cause a loss.

With regards to the scenario you've given, no fraud would have been committed because the buyer was under no legal duty to disclose such information

Answer (score 2):

In general, the "value" of anything is the price a buyer and seller agree on - if one has knowledge the other doesn't, that is not fraud. Fraud requires a deliberate deception - if, in response to a direct question from the seller, the buyer were to state that the stamp was not valuable, *knowing that it is*, then they have committed fraud.

Comment: Is that really true? Has a buyer ever been successfully persecuted for this kind of deception?

Comment: @DaleM For it to be a fraudulent representation, B would have to state it in a way that is objectively verifiable as false (for instance, by saying that the official price is 5 €). However, saying "the stamp is not valuable" still retains enough subjectivity to preempt a viable claim of fraud.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Shazamos's result, but not with his reasoning. B's offer contains several statements: of fact and opinion.

First, by offering A 100€, B expresses his current intention to enter into a legally binding contract with A in regard to the stamp. By accepting the offer, one can infer that A was induced by this statement. However, the statement is true, as stamp and money changed hands.

Second, B's offer implies that the stamp is worth 100€. Despite the market value of the stamp being considerably higher, this statement is true, because B only expresses that the stamp is *at least* 100€ worth to him personally. By contrast, where B is a professional stamp collector, who knows the market value of the stamp, and A relies on B's expertise, the result maybe different.

In conclusion: without holding himself as an expert to A, B did not fraudulently misrepresent to him.

Comment: Are you saying that if *B* is known to *A* to be a philatelist then the transaction *is* fraudulent?

Comment: Potentially, yes.

Comment: @SingulaereEntitaet I am NOT voting down this answer (and I never vote articulated ones, regardless of whether I agree with them), but the last part of your analysis and conclusion are wrong. B's expertise is irrelevant to the issue of fraud because A did not hire B to advise him on stamp worth. B's expertise and/or his ostentation thereof does not by itself create a fiduciary duty with respect to A.

Comment: @feetwet See my comment to this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Under U.S. law, the answer is somewhat similar to the one given by @ShazamoMorebucks but there are additional prerequisites for the transaction to be considered a *fraud* or scam.

One *prima facie* element of fraud is A's *reasonable reliance* on B's representation. Here, A and B are on the opposite sides of a contract, whence it is evident and expected that each party will pursue his own interest. In this context of competing interests, it was not reasonable for A to rely on B's statements (absent any guarantee or objective assurance given by B). Moreover, B did not even state that the stamp is worth 100€: He merely offered 100€ to A in exchange for the stamp.

Another *prima facie* element of fraud is that A *incurs a loss* as a result of B's representation. ShazamoMorebucks refers to the absence of a legal duty of disclosure, but I take a different approach:

It is wrong to conclude that A incurred a loss at all. Up until the transaction, A underestimated his stamp to the extent that he "*agree[d] happily*" when B offered 100€ in exchange for the stamp. A's reaction and decision show that A deemed the transaction profitable. The fact that A later realized he could have asked more money does not render the transaction an instance of fraud.